# Two questions about Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I'm migrating from Eclipse to Netbeans, and two problems are happening:

1. I created my own file template, but how can I set a default for the "Created file name" field?
   I always name my files as `Class_Name.class.php` and Netbeans doesn't allow me to edit the field to add the ".class".
2. Sometimes, the mouse cursor change from the default text pointer to arrow pointer and I have to close and re-open Netbeans to go back to normal. Anyone had the same problem?

I'm running a Mac OS X 10.6.5 and Netbeans 6.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Tools|Templates, and in the template manager find the template in question. (Unintuitively) Right-Click on the template and select Properties. You can change the *File Name* property here, but in NB 6.9.1 it seems a bit quirky to me. For example, I changed the *File Name* for the PHP Class template from `PHPClass` to `PHPCLass.class`. It certainly put the `.class` on to the filename, but gave me `PHPCLass.class` in the *File Name* field on the New PHP Class dialog (File|New File...|etc., or any of the number of other ways to get to a new file dialog). I had to deselect the .class part manually to give the file a name that still included the .class. More annoying, however, was that **if the value of the `File Name` property contains an extension-looking piece, then the automatic generation of the `.php` was *surpressed***!  I had to go back and change the `File Name` property to "PHPClass.class.php" and deal with retaining both the .class and the .php.

   I tried going a different route, by attempting to add a new extension in Tools|Options|Miscellaneous|Files, but that would not let me create an extension that contained a period.

   I have not found a property, yet, that controls the created name directly.
2. I've never seen that, ever. I'm not on a Mac, so that might be something quirky/localized to the Mac look and feel (try a different one--Napkin is always entertaining for about 90 seconds, :-) until you realize not all controls are accounted for), or maybe (and more scary) a quirk/bug in the native-end of Mac's implementation of Swing components.